# Does there exist a django app for Facebook's realtime updates API?

Tags: django, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I tried looking for a Django app to interface with Facebook's [realtime updates API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/api/realtime/), but couldn't find one.  I started [my own implementation](https://github.com/ash211/django-fb-realtime), but it's neither finished nor working yet.

Are there any Django apps that already take care of this?

My use case is I'd like to keep a local cache of Facebook's User model to prevent querying the Graph API on every page request.  I'd like to segment content from my users into groups

Answer (score 2):

This appears to do what you need: https://github.com/rmaceissoft/django-facebook-realtime